# Update a variable in daemon - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon

I have a daemon which processes some records and has some `stored_data` in its memory. I want to update that data constantly  based on some events that occur.

I know I have to use a background thread which will update the changes back to the `stored_data` in my main memory. But how to pass the data to the thread?

Currently the ways I know are:
1) Expose the background thread as a service which will expose add apis
2) Make the background thread poll a certain location which is expected to be the common place where the additions are logged and pick it from there.

Let me know if thats correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you think "polling" or "update at intervals", use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to execute "check for data update" tasks at regular intervals. You do not need a daemon thread to do that, and, in my experience, working with scheduled tasks makes for code that is easier to maintain. E.g. in this case it will separate the `stored_data` from Threads which is a good thing because Threads do not own data (data is contained in objects which do not have to be threads, e.g. you can pass the `stored_data` variable to the `Runnable` that is executed by the thread).

When you think "event driven", a daemon thread is appropriate because it will process the events as soon as they occur (no delay). You can decide to let the daemon thread do the work for the event, or create tasks for the event and let those tasks be executed by an ExecutorService like a [CachedThreadPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28%29). Have a look at the "[Watching a directory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)" tutorial on how to receive file-system events for such a daemon thread.